# Matlab parfor taking longer than normal for

Tags: matlab, time, parfor

I have a MATLAB code where I am using `parfor` to reduce the amount of time taken by `for` to do some image processing tasks. Basically,it is taking two images and after doing some mathematical calculations, it produces a scalar qunatity called `EucDist`. For this, one image is kept fixed and another image is generated by a FORTRAN code which is taking around 20 seconds to do that. Below is the outline of my code:

```
matlabpool open
gray1 = some_image(8192,200);

dep = 0.04:0.01:0.40;       % Parameter 1
vel = 1.47:0.01:1.72;       % Parameter 2

dist = zeros(length(dep),length(vel));

tic
parfor i = 1:length(dep)
    ans = zeros(1,length(vel));
    for j = 1:length(vel)

        % Updating the Input.txt file
        fname = sprintf('Input_%.2d%s',i,'.txt');
        fid=fopen(fname,'w');
        fprintf(fid,'%-5.2f\n%-5.2f\n%.2d',dep(i),vel(j),i);
        fclose(fid);

        % Running my fortran code to generate another .dat file (Note that I have already compiled this code outside these loops)
        system(['./editcrfl ' fname]);

        % Calling IMAGE_GEN script incorporating the above .dat file 
        system('IMAGE_GEN');

        system(sprintf('IMAGE_GEN %d',i));

        gray2 = some_image(8192,200);

        % Doing some mathematical calculations and getting a value say 'EucDist' 
        - - - - - - - 
        - - - - - - -
        ans(j) = EucDist; 

    end
    dist(i,:) = ans;
    fclose('all');
end
fprintf('Total time taken: %f\n',toc); 
matlabpool close
```

There are two major problems that I am facing with the above code.

First, the `dist` matrix is not able to store all the `EucDist` generated. Ideally `dist` matrix should be of size 37 X 26 but it is only 37 X 1 and all the values are zeros in that. Though I have checked that all 37 X 26 values are getting calculated but don't know why it is not getting stored in `dist`.

Second, the total time taken when I am using `parfor` is somewhere around 9.5 hours whereas for normal `for` it is taking only 5.5 hours.

Can someone please help me to get rid of the above two problems?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd guess that many image processing functions are already parallelized (hard to say without full code or a minimal example), so you won't see a benefit. Also, since it looks like you're also doing file io, whether you get any speed-up will depend on your file system and if you physical media supports parallel access.

Comment: Actually I am calculating Euclidean distance between images using a new approach. So it's not a built in function and that's the reason I am trying to parallelizing it by my own. However while calculating this modified Euclidean distance, I am using several builtin MATLAB functions. You can find an outline of that algorithm [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985718/euclidean-distance-between-images). Also, I think my physical media fully supports parallel access as I have seen some significant running time improvement over few simple examples.

Comment: `fft2`/`ifft2` are intrinsically multithreaded, as are most linear algebra operations ([see here](http://www.mathworks.com/discovery/matlab-multicore.html) and [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2009/04/17/multithreaded-fft-functions-in-matlab-r2009a/)).

Comment: I am sorry to say this but that is not my concern at all. You can see that in my code, I am generating an image using a particular `dep(i)` and `vel(j)` and this is the actual part which is causing a running time overhead for my program which takes around 20 sec for one image generation. That's the reason I thought of using `parfor` so that each processor can have their own copy of Image generation code and produce an image according to their `vel` & `dep` value. What I think is, ideally this should reduce the running time by 1/12 for 12 processor but that is not the case. Can u explain this?

Comment: Can someone please help me into this?